# Writing to file only at the end of the execution in my bash shell

Tags: c

I am writing my own shell. I am facing a problem with the commands like `C1 | C2 > file` or `C1 | C2 >> file`. When I execute a command like `ls | grep .c > a.txt` , I get the result of `ls | grep` only when I terminate the program. But I want to get it during the execution.

Code from **main.c**:

```
 if (countPipes == 1 && strstr(userInput, ">>") != NULL){
                token = NULL;

                resetC(cmd);

                resetC(cmdPipe);

                token = strtok(userInput, ">>");

                char *piped = strdup(token);

                token = strtok(NULL, ">>");

                char *file = strdup(token);

                file = skipwhite(file);

                token = strtok(piped, "|");

                c1 = strdup(token);

                token = strtok(NULL, "|");

                c2 = strdup(token);
                c2 = skipwhite(c2);


                splitCommands(c1, cmd);

                splitCommands(c2, cmdPipe);

                execPipedCommandsRed(cmd, cmdPipe, file);

                memset(userInput, '\0', 1000);
            }
```

Code from **functions.c**:

```
void execPipedCommandsRed(char **cmd, char **cmdPiped, char *file){
    int pipeOne[2], status, ret_val, s;

    status = pipe(pipeOne);
    if (status < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    int k;
    int e = dup(1);
    pid_t p1, p2, w;
    int s2 = dup(1);
    p1 = fork();

    if (p1 < 0) {
        printf("Fork failed!\n");
    }

    if (p1 == 0) {

        close(pipeOne[READ]);

        dup2(pipeOne[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);

        close(pipeOne[WRITE]);

        if (execvp(cmd[0], cmd) < 0) {
            perror("Lathos");
        }

    } else {
        p2 = fork();

        if (p2 < 0) {
            printf("Fork failed\n");
        }

        if (p2 == 0) {

            close(pipeOne[WRITE]);

            dup2(pipeOne[READ], STDIN_FILENO);

            close(pipeOne[READ]);

            k = open(file, O_WRONLY| O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0644);
            if (k < 0) {
                puts("error k");
            }

            dup2(k, 1);
            close(k);

            if (execvp(cmdPiped[0], cmdPiped) < 0) {
                perror("Lathos!");
            }
        } else {
            // parent is waiting
            waitpid(-1, &s, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
            printBash();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You *are* getting it during execution, but it's buffered for performance.

Comment: "The program" -- which program? `grep` should be exiting pretty promptly, and by the time it exits, all of _its_ buffers will be flushed. OTOH, if your parent process is holding an open copy of the FD writing from `ls`'s output to `grep`'s input in the parent process, that'll stop `grep` from seeing end-of-input and being able to flush its output and exit. For debugging this kind of thing, `lsof` is your friend, to be able to look at which file descriptors a running process has open; can also just look at the `/proc/<pid>/fd` directory listing, with the PID of your C program.

Comment: Also, why is `bash` tagged at all here? None of your code is written in bash. If you're writing _your own_ shell, that's _your_ shell, it's not bash; bash is a very specific shell, written by Chet Ramy; no other shell is bash. You might describe it as "bash-like".

Comment: Ι press 'ps' and the grep command is hanging and not terminated. I can see the opened fds, but i cant see the error..

Answer (score 0):

> When i execute a command like `ls | grep .c > a.txt`, i get the result of `ls | grep` only when i terminate the program.

The traditional POSIX shell behaviour is that `stdout` is line-buffered only when it goes into a terminal ([`isatty`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) returns `1`), otherwise it is block-buffered. See [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf) for buffering descriptions.

If you'd like matching files to be output into `stdout` as they are found, instead of `ls | grep .c > a.txt` use the following command:

```
stdbuf --output=L find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.c" > a.txt
```

[`stdbuf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.h) allows to explicitly specify the desired buffering mode. And `find` outputs one filename per-line, unlike plain `ls`.

You can do `ls` and `grep`, but that is sub-optimal in the number of processes involved and that each process must have its output buffering specified explicitly:

```
stdbuf --output=L ls -1 | stdbuf --output=L egrep '\.c$' > a.txt
```

Notes:

1. `stdbuf` only affects C standard streams and some heavily optimised applications may not use C standard streams at all, so that `stdbuf` may have no effect.
2. `grep .c` matches anything that has character `c` at non-0 position. Whereas `find -name "*.c"` matches only files with extension `.c`. So does `egrep '\.c$'`.
3. `ls` outputs multiple files per line, but `grep` filtering expects one file per line. `ls -1` outputs one file per line.

Comment: Everything `stdbuf` does the OP could also do in their own code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would upvote your code example.

Comment: My problem is not this specific command, but all of the commands with the format C1 | C2 | C3. I think the problem is somewhere in the file descs.